# Is it possible to show all inherited attributes and associations in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a complex data model and want to quickly show all inherited attributes and associations of a feature.

One possibility according to the EA-documentation would be to use Elements->Feature visibility (Ctrl+tab+y), but the option is unfortunately greyed out in the model. I guess this is a specific model setting or a limitation of the used EA-Version (Prof. Edition).

What (other) kind of possibilities do I have in Enterprise Architect Professional Edition to show inherited attributs and associations of a feature?

edit:
Below is a a screenshot of the greyed-out Feature Visibility, as requested in the comments. The model is the german street/traffic OKSTRA-model 2.017(EAP-file downloadable under www.okstra.de).

[image]

Comment: im not sure why the option would be greyed out, dont think its limited to an edition either

Comment: Definitely this is not a license issue. Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: Sure, I edited in a screenshot and the model-info.

Comment: is the diagram or element locked?

Comment: Ah, bingo. The diagram was locked and I was only looking for the element lock the entire time. That did solve the issue and it works as intended now. Thanks. If you convert it into a short answer I can accept it.

Comment: @Mart10 I posted an answer after seeing the picture - but not your comment. Please: post this as answer. I delete mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP had his diagram locked, preventing appearance modifications such as showing attributes